# zsh: permission denied: /Users/macbookpro/.zshrc

Tags: ios, flutter, sdk, environment-variables, hybrid

I'm new in flutter I want to set **flutter sdk** path in Mac OS (VS code) for this I'm fallow the **https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path** but when I run **$HOME/.zshrc** in Terminal It show error message **zsh: permission denied: /Users/macbookpro/.zshrc** I also apply this **[Terminal error: zsh: permission denied: ./startup.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53229221/terminal-error-zsh-permission-denied-startup-sh)** but this is not work for me.. can some one help me

Answer (score 20):

step.1

Open your terminal.

step.2

```
cd ~
vim .zshrc
```

step.3

Pass `i` to insert,and insert your flutter path(/bin:/Library/flutter/bin) behind `.bin:$PATH/`.

If you are done, press `esc` and enter `:wq`.

example

```
export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH/bin:/Library/flutter/bin"
```

Comment: have you try  `sudo vim .zshrc`

Answer (score 10):

If you want to evaluate its content inside your current zsh process, you can do a

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

You need to set the execute permission on the file, as you do for any other command which you want to execute, i.e.

```
chmod +x ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **Apple Silicon** and **macOS Ventura**, you can follow these steps:

1. Open Terminal.
2. Use the following command to open the `.zshrc` in the nano text editor:

> **nano .zshrc**

3. Add the Flutter path to the file by appending the following line:

> **export PATH="$PATH:/Users/{your_flutter_extracted_path}/bin"**

4. Save the changes by pressing `CTRL + O`, then exit Nano by pressing `CTRL + X`.
5. To verify that the path has been added successfully, run the following command in the Terminal:

> **which flutter**

It should display the path to Flutter similar to this:

> **/Users/{your_flutter_extracted_path}/bin/flutter**

If you see the correct Flutter path, you are all set and ready to use Flutter on your Apple Silicon macOS Ventura setup!

Answer (score 1):

For saving time, a little bit edited answer.

Commands in the terminal

```
cd ~
nano .zshrc
```

In the editor add path to the folder, for example

```
path+=('/usr/local/bin/ntfy')
```

Save, exit. Apply changes to current terminal

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

PS Check that in the file presents a line with export.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and run

```
source ~/.zshrc
sudo nano .zshrc
```

Then add the following path to the file:

```
export PATH=/Users/blackorbs/.android/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

Press "Control+X" then "Y" to save, then press Enter.

Close the terminal, reopen and run

```
flutter doctor
```

**don't forget to replace 'blackorbs' in the path with your your pc username**